# What happens if I modify ro.product.abilist64?

Tags: applications, root-access

I'm on a 32 bit SO (64 bit hardware). I built a 64 bit app, and somehow when it is built, it just turned to 32 bit (the app). So if I just add the `arm64-v8a` abi it should install?

I'm not asking if it will gonna work, of course will not work im just curious about it. I didn't found nothing about change it. Also I think my system will bootloop. I already saved the file, I just need restart  the phone.

**Edit:** I just can't bootloop my device now, because my phone number just got blocked so if I reset my phone I will lose my Signal/WhatsApp.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it got stuck in bootoop. But it was different from these bootloops, the phone didn't reset, it just kept playing the animation forever and forever (3 minutes)...

hopefully, i have `vim` on my android so i could edit without my pc and then back to normal. I hope someone read it before do it.